# Android SDK: Show one line at a time and proceed with onClick

Tags: android, sdk, onclick, textview, onclicklistener

I'm new to Java and the Android SDK but I'm willing to learn. What I want to do is to build an app that take a sentence, or a generic string and displays only one line of text, this is already coded. But I want to do is to proceed to the "next" line by clicking a button called something like "Proceed". So in short it is just offers you to read a little amount of text at a time and proceed b clicking a button.

This is how far I've got:

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:onClick="nextLine"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.xxx.xxx.xxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String s = "Iphone swag fanny pack, try-hard master cleanse pop-up elit deserunt vinyl. Odio mustache hoodie YOLO fap. Vegan godard labore tempor. Farm-to-table aute craft beer, YOLO bicycle rights artisan semiotics. Cosby sweater readymade eiusmod consectetur fap stumptown. Cliche keytar accusamus blue bottle, wayfarers locavore selfies elit aliqua chillwave lo-fi helvetica enim. Irony tofu blog, fap pickled pariatur odio wolf cliche vice sint pitchfork eiusmod cosby sweater polaroid.";
    final String[] words = s.split("\\s+");

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_box);
           StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
           for (String s : words){
             builder.append(s+" ");
           tx.setText(builder.toString());
       }
    }});

}}
```

As of now no text is loaded into the textView and the button loads all of the text at once when clicked on with no support to "reclick" it.

Any ideas?

Best regards,

**Update:**
I've made a counter to account for which word should be printed on the screen. I have another question: how do I go about to make tre words (or any number of words) to show instead of just one? I tried to fiddle with indexranges but I can't seem to get the hang of it. This is how my MainActivity.java looks like now:

```
package com.xxx.xxx.xxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int counter;
    String s = "Iphone swag fanny pack, try-hard master cleanse pop-up elit deserunt vinyl. Odio mustache hoodie YOLO fap. Vegan godard labore tempor. Farm-to-table aute craft beer, YOLO bicycle rights artisan semiotics. Cosby sweater readymade eiusmod consectetur fap stumptown. Cliche keytar accusamus blue bottle, wayfarers locavore selfies elit aliqua chillwave lo-fi helvetica enim. Irony tofu blog, fap pickled pariatur odio wolf cliche vice sint pitchfork eiusmod cosby sweater polaroid.";
    final String[] words = s.split("\\s+");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_box);
        counter = 0;
        tx.setText(words[counter]);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           counter++;
           tx.setText(words[counter]);
       }
    });

}}
```

Comment: did you checked that your words have split's your text  correctly. ?

Comment: Regarding the second question, counter is used to point at the beginning of the next page with `n` words. On every button click you should: create a `StringBuilder`; in loop iterate over `n` words  starting from next page (current counter value) -> append word to resulting string, check boundary conditions (last page can contain less than `n` words), increment counter; set resulting string to a TextView

Answer (score 2):

Your code assigns TextView value on every iteration adding one word after each iteration. That's why all text is loaded.

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
       TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_box);
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

       for (String s : words){
         builder.append(s+" ");
         tx.setText(builder.toString());
       }
```

If you want to display one word per click, make a counter which acts as an index for words array and increments after every click. And assign "current index word" to a text field.

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I have a followup question, would you mind helping with that aswell?

Comment: Thank you, I updated my post with the question. In short I want to display n number of words instead of just one.

Answer (score 2):

First of all move the `TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_box);` to the `onCreate` method. There is no need to get text view each time the button is clicked. Therefore text view should be stored as attribute in your class. Additionally make sure your text was split correctly. The last thing needed is a little bit of logic. Get the number of elements in the `words` table. Create also some counter which is set to the current word. On each button click get the words pointed to by counter (words[i]) and increment that counter. When the counter reaches the maximum number of elements you could reset it to 0.